# Try Catch Block Java

Tags: java

I need to update the first section of code below so that its in a try catch block to accommodate error handling based on exception type. I have two exception types, ParseException which is thrown as part of the outboundErrorVoValidator, and also OutboundErrorDataException. When I use test data which should throw a ParseException, it is not caught using the second block of code, but it works fine in the first. Why does it not get caught in the second block of code?

```
public StoredOutboundErrorCaseVO updateCase(UpdateCaseDataVO updateCaseDataVO, Long caseId) throws ParseException, OutboundErrorDataException {

Map<String, String> exceptionsList = null;
    exceptionsList = outboundErrorVoValidator.validateUpdateCaseData(updateCaseDataVO);
    if (!exceptionsList.isEmpty()) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
        errorMessage.setErrors(exceptionsList);
        errorMessage.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        errorMessage.setTimeStamp(new Date());
        throw new OutboundErrorDataException(errorMessage);
    }
```

Second attempt:

```
public StoredOutboundErrorCaseVO updateCase(UpdateCaseDataVO updateCaseDataVO, Long caseId)  {

    try {
            Map<String, String> exceptionsList = null;
            exceptionsList = outboundErrorVoValidator.validateUpdateCaseData(updateCaseDataVO);
            if (!exceptionsList.isEmpty()) {
                ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
                errorMessage.setErrors(exceptionsList);
                errorMessage.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
                errorMessage.setTimeStamp(new Date());
                throw new OutboundErrorDataException(errorMessage);
            }
        } catch (OutboundErrorDataException f) {
            f.getErrorMessage();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

My validateUpdateCaseData method looks like this, might be useful

```
public Map<String, String> validateUpdateCaseData(UpdateCaseDataVO updateCaseDataVO) throws ParseException {
```

Comment: What is a hierarchy of these two exception classes from Exception Class?

Comment: The `catch` blocks simply call `getMessage()` or `getErrorMessage()` but then do nothing with what these methods return, so you would see nothing if the exception is caught. You probably want to replace these with `e.printStackTrace();` or `System.err.println(e.getMessage());`.

Comment: OutboundErrorDataException and ParseException both extend Exception @Arun

Comment: You state that your test data "should" throw `ParseException`, can you add the test case or add logging to show that it, in fact, does throw that Exception?